# i want to print text of my images one by one which are present inside one folder using for loop

Tags: java, selenium

**scrape** one by one image text from a folder.this one for only one image.how to do for all the images

```
public static String crackImage(String filepath) throws TesseractException {
        File imgfile = new File(filepath);
            ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
            instance.setDatapath("C:\\selenium_work\\ScrapingText.PDF\\tessdata");
            
            String result = instance.doOCR(imgfile);
            return result;  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TesseractException {
        
         String textdata = ImageScraping.crackImage("C:\\selenium_work\\ScrapingText.PDF\\image\\IMG_20190305_152800__01.jpg");
         System.out.println(textdata);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the images from the given URL like:

1. Locate all [`<img>` tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) and extract their [`src` attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp) using i.e. [XPath locator](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=55281024) of `//img`

   ```
   List<String> imagesUrls = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img"))
           .stream()
           .map(img -> img.getAttribute("src"))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
2. Download all the images into the folder of your choice using [OkHTTP client library](https://square.github.io/okhttp/):

   ```
   for (String imageUrl : imagesUrls) {
       Request request = new Request.Builder().url(imageUrl).build();
       Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
       File downloadedLogo = new File("C:\\selenium_work\\ScrapingText.PDF\\image\\" + imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
       BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(downloadedLogo));
       sink.writeAll(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).source());
       sink.close();
   }
   ```
3. Once done you should be able to call your `crackImage` function for each downloaded file via Files.walk() method:

   ```
   Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\selenium_work\\ScrapingText.PDF\\image"))
           .forEach(file -> System.out.println(crackImage(file.toAbsolutePath().toString())));
   ```

Comment: actually my images are not in url...someone send me list of visiting card in png format

Comment: In that case you have all the images already in a folder and can skip the first two steps. You only need to follow the step 3 as described by  Dmitri.